# React - Calling a function from content management system html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, href, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I have an odd case that I need to solve.  I have a react app that dynamically injects html content via (dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: data}}).  Think of it as a pseudo content management system with some legacy html content with some embedded javascript method calls, so I can't change the following html block.

Example embedded html block (injected using dangerouslySetInnerHTML):

```
<p><a href="javascript:showvideo('http://urldir/vid.mp4',vwidth,vheight,0)">Launch vid.</a></p>
```

in my react component:

```
function showvideo(url,width,height,id){
  console.log('called showvideo')
}
```

I keep getting 'Uncaught ReferenceError: showvideo is not defined'

How do I call a function with `<a href='javascript:myfunction'>` in react?

Comment: Can u share more info on where the `showVideo` function is called?

Comment: @ToniBardinaComas it gets called when you click on the <a href> shown above (inside the p tag).  This html string is stored in a database (please don't ask why), then injected via dangerouslySetInnerHTML() on the front end.